# Entity framework, how to convert from proxy to object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm loving EF so far. My project has started crashing when its trying to convert a System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Badge to Badge. I don't know what to do. I've read the documentation on Proxies and I sort of understand it. I don't want to disable proxy functionality if it is beneficial to have it?

How can I get around this? Basically I call a function MyFunc(myBadge); And because MyFunc takes a parameter of type Badge it crashes. Code is below:

```
foreach(Badge B in badgesOfBadgeType) {

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(GlobalHelper.GetCurrentContext().Server.MapPath("~") + "bin/MM.dll";
Type classs = assembly.GetType("MM.Helpers.BadgeHelper");
string methodName = "DoesUserEventUnlockBadge_"+B.ID;
MethodInfo methodInfo = classs.GetMethod(methodName);

if (methodInfo != null)
{
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
    object[] parametersArray = new object[] { B, UE };
    bool didUnlock = (bool)methodInfo.Invoke(null, parametersArray);

    if (didUnlock)
    {
        unlockedBadges.Add(B);
    }
}
```

}

calling func:

```
public static bool DoesUserEventUnlockBadge_1(Badge B, UserEvent UE)
        {
            //Check here..
            return true;
        }
```

New error, when I go db.Badges.find(b); and use that (I.E a non proxy)

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The specified parameter type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Badge_90C17B99EFACD091308AD8F9030C6441D90D4237AC5630A4C2F673A79A186B27' is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.
Parameter name: parameter
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameterCollection.Add(ObjectParameter parameter)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateQuery[T](String queryString, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindInStore(WrappedEntityKey key, String keyValuesParamName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at MusingMonkey.Helpers.BadgeHelper.UnlockedBadgesForEvent(BaseDBContext db, UserEvent UE, User user) in C:\Users\William-Business\Desktop\TWB\TWB Central\Projects\MusingMonkey\MusingMonkey\Helpers\BadgeHelper.cs:line 31
   at MusingMonkey.Helpers.UserIdeaHelper.PushVoteToIdea(BaseDBContext db, Nullable`1 id, String direction) in C:\Users\William-Business\Desktop\TWB\TWB Central\Projects\MusingMonkey\MusingMonkey\Helpers\UserIdeaHelper.cs:line 164
   at MusingMonkey.Controllers.IdeasController.Vote(Nullable`1 id, String direction) in C:\Users\William-Business\Desktop\TWB\TWB Central\Projects\MusingMonkey\MusingMonkey\Controllers\IdeasController.cs:line 23
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: "it crashes" what is the exception message and which line throws the exception? And what is the signature of the `BadgeHelper.DoesUserEventUnlockBadge_` method?

Comment: Proxied objects derive from your own class. The proxy object for `Badge` is assignable to a variable with type `Badge`. Make sure `Badge` resolves to the correct type (if you have an unrelated type Badge in a different assembly or namespace), and make sure `badgesOfBadgeType` really does contain only `Badge` objects, and that `DoesUserEventUnlockBadge` takes that same `Badge` type.

Comment: By the way, dynamically calling `DoesUserEventUnlockBadge_1`/`DoesUserEventUnlockBadge_2`/`DoesUserEventUnlockBadge_3` like that? That's pretty ugly. Is it possible to rework that into a `DoesUserEventUnlockBadge` function that looks at the passed badge's ID?

Comment: Object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Badge_90C17B99EFACD091308AD8F9030C6441D90D4237AC5630A4C2F673A79A186B27' cannot be converted to type 'MusingMonkey.Models.Badge'. Have attached the other code (of the calling function. The error occurs on the bool didUnlock line

Comment: That is pretty ugly code. Maybe you should first redesign the algorithm and get rid of all that reflection.

Comment: Hey hvd, ues I could do that, but then within that proposed function I'd have to route it out to another function anyway? or have conditionals within that function & handle everything in there? Which i dont wnat to do

Comment: I just cahnged things and accessed Badge from the db.Badges directly and got this error

Comment: I don't see another way to do without reflection? Each badge has its own prerequistes for getting that badge unlocked, so each badge should have a function to return true/false? How else can you route it around..

Comment: @Baconbeastnz As for "but then within that proposed function I'd have to route it out to another function anyway", yes, but even reworking it in the style of `void f(int x) { switch (x) { case 1: f_1(); break; case 3: f_3(); break; case 4: f_4(); break; } }` would be an improvement over this, IMO.

Comment: "New error, when I go db.Badges.find(b); and use that" -- yes, `db.Badges.Find()` takes the key value (`b.Id`) as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why , but something was wrong with the reflection, works if I just send it to a method normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false" in your dbContext class.